# Readable alternative to two-dimensional switch statement?

Tags: java, arrays, switch-statement, readability

I need to fire different methods depending on the value of `parent` and `child` which are different values of the same enum type. Currently I do this:

```
switch (parent)
{
  case DEPARTMENT:
  {
    switch (child)
    {
      case TERMINAL:
      {
        event1();
        break;
      }
      case OPERATOR:
      {
        event2();
        break;
      }
    }
    break;
  }
  case OPERATOR:
  {
    switch (child)
    {
      case TERMINAL:
      {
        event3();
        break;
      }
    }
    break;
  }
}
```

The actual code contains 5-10 cases, with each case executing one or more long lines of code (methods with multiple arguments).

I tried populating a two-dimensional array with `Runnable`s but it executed 2x slower.

Is there an alternative way of writing this, which would be more readable, yet nearly as fast?

Comment: Are lambdas that are coming in Java 8 acceptable?

Comment: Are `parent` and `child` the same enum type, or different types?

Comment: @ajb, the question already answers this. It says they are of the same enum type.

Comment: @hexafraction, ideally not (JDK8 can't be legally used in production yet) but post the answer and we'll let people vote :)

Comment: @Gili Can't today, sadly. Maybe someone else will post, and getmy upvote *hint, hint*

Comment: _"Please include a rough estimate of the performance difference between your answer and the two-dimensional switch (test it!). This will help us compare answers."_ Um, no, that's your responsibility.

Comment: This is more suited for [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Please comment when downvoting, otherwise I don't know the cause.

Comment: I find this to be an interesting and useful question. And yes, a good answer becomes a great answer by including performance measurements.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul thanks for the edits. Don't forget to upvote the question. Hopefully someone will come up with an even better answer than the one I've marked as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An integer selector calculated from the combined values of `parent` and `child` will be faster:

```
public enum Stuff { DEPARTMENT, OPERATOR, TERMINAL };
Stuff parent = ...;
Stuff child  = ...;

int selector = parent.ordinal() * Stuff.values().length + child.ordinal();
switch(selector)
{
    case 0 : // parent=DEPARTMENT child=DEPARTMENT
        ...
    case 1 : // parent=DEPARTMENT child=OPERATOR
        ...
        ...
    case 3 : // parent=OPERATOR child=DEPARTMENT
        ...
    case 8:  // parent=TERMINAL child=TERMINAL
        ...
}
```

Some combinations may not be meaningful, just omit them and provide a `default` with nothing in it.  You could also define constants in the enum:

```
private static final int n = values().length; // for brevity
public static final int DEPARTMENT_DEPARTMENT = DEPARTMENT.ordinal() * n + DEPARTMENT.ordinal()
        ...
```

and use those in the case statements.

Comment: Unfortunately, `DEPARTMENT_DEPARTMENT` is not a constant expression, so it cannot be used inside a switch statement. The numbers are less readable and reliable.

Comment: The results are in: this code is slightly faster (~5%) than the two-dimensional switch but I find readability to be worse due to the `constant expression` problem. My primary goal is to improve readability (and reliability in case enum values move around) so unfortunately I don't think this answer does it for me.

Comment: I've accepted your answer because it is the best of the bunch, but I ended up keeping the two-dimensional switch statement for readability (I know, it's a subjective decision). Thank you for this insightful approach. Hopefully I'll get to use it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
class SwitchTable {
    private static class EventKey {
        private EnumType parent;
        private EnumType child;
        public EventKey (EnumType p, EnumType c) { parent=p; child=c; }
        public int HashCode () { ...something... }
    } 
    private HashMap<EventKey, Integer> events;
    public void setEvent (EnumType parent, EnumType child, int eventNumber) {
         ... add a map entry to events that maps new EventKey(parent,child) 
         ... to eventNumber
    }
    public int whichEvent (EnumType parent, EnumType child) {
         ... return the map entry for new EventKey(parent,child) or 0 if not found
    }
}

// do this once to set up
SwitchTable switches = new SwitchTable();
switches.setEvent (EnumType.DEPARTMENT, EnumType.TERMINAL, 1);
switches.setEvent (EnumType.DEPARTMENT, EnumType.OPERATOR, 2);
switches.setEvent (EnumType.OPERATOR, EnumType.TERMINAL, 3);

// then
switch (switches.whichEvent(parent, child)) {
    case 1:  event1();  break;
    case 2:  event2();  break;
    case 3:  event3();  break;
}
```

I'm too lazy to fill in all the details, but you get the idea.  This should work even if the parent and child are different enum types.  You could use a different implementation for SwitchTable (e.g. set up a 1- or 2-dimensional array to hold the event values instead of a HashMap).  I haven't tested this and don't know how it compares speed-wise.  I hope I didn't make any dumb syntax errors.

EDIT: `whichEvent` doesn't have to return an integer.  You could make it a new `enum` type whose names reflect the kinds of actions you might want to take.  That should improve readability.

Comment: The results are in: your answer is 5x slower than the original code. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the cases, to archive readability compromises performance. Here is a solution works **ONLY** with java7.

```
public class SwitchArray {

    public enum Stuff {
        DEPARTMENT, OPERATOR, TERMINAL
    };

    static Stuff parent = Stuff.DEPARTMENT;
    static Stuff child = Stuff.OPERATOR;

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        switch (SwitchArray.parent.toString() + "_" + SwitchArray.child.toString()) {
        case "DEPARTMENT_OPERATOR":
            System.out.println("hey!");
            break;
        case "DEPARTMENT_TERMINAL":
            System.out.println("ha!");
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Ouch! 26x slower than the original :) I'll say one thing for this question: it's teaching me a lot about Java performance I didn't know before.

Answer (score 0):

Add a method to your enum (I'm calling it a MyEnum)

public void doFireEvent(MyEnum child) {
  // a single switch here for each enum
}

Slightly cleaner IMO, at least it moves all that code to the enum class so you won't see it.  :-)

(added later). A drawback of this is that your MyEnum class must have knowledge of / access to the event1() etc. methods, which may be impossible or inappropriate.

Comment: You can't do that, because each event depends on *two* enum values, not one.

Comment: Yes you can - call `parent.doFireEvent(child);`

Comment: You're right, though as you mention this would require me to embed knowledge of event1() etc into the enum which doesn't make sense in my context.

Comment: Perhaps rename the method `figureEvent() or curryEvent()`, and have it return a single int or enum that caller can use in a single switch.  Though at this point your original nested switch is looking pretty good!

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be made much more readable just by using better indentation and formatting techniques and also encapsulating all this dirty logic within the enum itself.  It
s really your formatting more than anything that makes it so difficult to trace.

```
public enum MyEnum {

    OPERATOR, TERMINAL;

    public static void execute(MyEnum parent, MyEnum child) {
        switch(parent) {
            case OPERATOR:
                switch(child) {
                    case OPERATOR: event1(); break;
                    case TERMINAL: event2(); break;
                }
            break;
            case TERMINAL:
                switch(child) {
                    case TERMINAL: event3(); break;
                }
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The simplified question is misleading. The actual code contains 5-10 cases, with each case executing one or more long lines of code (methods with multiple arguments). I appreciated the suggestion though.